# how to refer to a JButton that have not been declared?

Tags: java

For example:

```
panelname.add(new JButton("ButtonName"));
```

instead of :

```
JButton X = new JButton("ButtonName");
panelname.add(X);
```

In the first one, how do I use "X"?

Comment: `Panelname.getComponents();` and then iterate to find the one you want?

Comment: If `X` is not defined, you can't use it. Why can't you make the first code like the second?

Comment: yes i ll do it but what is the difference between the two?

Comment: As you saw, in the first one you don't get a handle to the object but in the 2nd one you get a handle called `X`. Other than that there is no difference.